# Wordpress theme doesn't read my translations from pt_BR.po file

Tags: theme-development, translation

I used PoEdit to create my **.pot** file. Added some translations, then created a **.po** file alongside with automatically created **.mo** file.

My .po file looks like this:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: xxx\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2020-04-16 15:45+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2020-04-17 12:28+0200\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: pt_BR\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.3\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: ..\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n > 1);\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: _e;__\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: .\n"

#: 404.php:7
msgid "Nie znaleziono strony."
msgstr "Página não encontrada."
```

Following all of the tutorials, I added these two files to *wp-content/themes/mytheme/languages* and also changed **wp-config** file by adding this line:

```
define( 'WPLANG', 'pt_BR' );
```

Not really sure why this doesn't work. My site still displays its original version of these strings. Has anyone had a problem like this? Or maybe I omitted some steps. I'm using *Wordpress 5.4*

Comment: Did you also set your Site Language in Settings/General?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it was necessary. So there's no other way to have an admin dashboard in one language and use translations for website in another? Either way, thanks, that solves partly my problem!

Comment: I don't know if that is possible. Perhaps you should post that as another question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the files to `wp-content/languages/themes/[theme name]-pt_BR.mo` and `.po`.

Comment: To clarify - I added subdirectory named 'themes/mythemename' to wp-content/languages and there I pasted these two files named: mythemename-pt_BR.po and mythemename-pt_BR.mo. Still nothing